# How to pass quoted arguments but with blank spaces in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

I have a file with these arguments and their values ​​this way

```
# parameters.txt

VAR1 001
VAR2 aaa
VAR3 'Hello World'
```

and another file to configure like this

```
# example.conf

VAR1 = 020
VAR2 = kab
VAR3 = ''
```

when I want to get the values in a function I use this command

```
while read p; do
  VALUE=$(echo $p | awk '{print $2}')
done < parameters.txt
```

the firsts arguments throw the right values, but the last one just gets the 'Hello for the blank space, my question is how do I get the entire 'Hello World' value?

Comment: Double quoting the variable should fix this. i.e. "$p"

Comment: How does `example.conf` come into play? Do you need code that can handle _both_ formats - with or without a `=` between the key and the value?

Comment: @JacobH: While it's always good practice to double-quote variable references in POSIX-like shell programming (unless you specifically want word splitting and globbing to happen), this won't fix the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `bash`, there is no need to use `awk`: **`read` and [shell parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) can be combined to solve your problem**:

```
while read -r name rest; do
  # Drop the '= ' part, if present.
  [[ $rest == '= '* ]] && value=${rest:2} || value=$rest
  # $value now contains the line's value,
  # but *including* any enclosing ' chars, if any.
  # Assuming that there are no *embedded* ' chars., you can remove them
  # as follows:
  value=${value//\'/}
done < parameters.txt
```

`read` by default also breaks a line into fields by whitespace, like `awk`, but unlike `awk` it has the ability to assign the *remainder* of the line to a varaible, namely the *last* one, if fewer variables than fields found are specified;
`read`'s `-r` option is generally worth specifying to avoid unexpected interpretation of `\` chars. in the input.

---

As for your solution attempt:

**`awk` doesn't know about *quoting* in input** - by default it breaks input into fields by whitespace, irrespective of quotation marks.
Thus, a string such as `'Hello World'` is simply broken into fields `'Hello` and `World'`.

However, in your case you can split each input line into its key and value using a carefully crafted FS value (FS is the input field separator, which can be also be set via option `-F`; the command again assumes `bash`, this time for use of `<(...)`, a so-called [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), and `$'...'`, an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)):

```
while IFS= read -r value; do
   # Work with $value...
done < <(awk -F$'^[[:alnum:]]+ (= )?\'?|\'' '{ print $2 }' parameters.txt)
```

Again the assumption is that values contain no *embedded* `'` instances.

Field separator regex `$'^[[:alnum:]]+ (= )?\'?|\''` splits each line so that `$2`, the 2nd field, contains the value, stripped of enclosing `'` chars., if any.

---

**`xargs`** is the rare exception among the standard utilities in that it ***does* understand single- and double-quoted strings** (yet also without support for *embedded* quotes).

Thus, you could take advantage of `xargs`' ability to implicitly strip enclosing quotes when it passes arguments to the specified command, which defaults to `echo` (again assumes `bash`):

```
while read -r name rest; do
  # Drop the '= ' part, if present.
  [[ $rest == '= '* ]] && value=${rest:2} || value=$rest
  # $value now contains the line's value, strippe of any enclosing
  # single quotes by `xargs`.
done < <(xargs -L1  < parameters.txt)
```

`xargs -L1` process one (`1`) line (`-L`) at a time and implicitly invokes `echo` with all tokens found on each line, with any enclosing quotes removed from the individual tokens.

Comment: I need to learn how exactly this code works, but does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @AbdelP. My pleasure; I've added more information and links that may be helpful.

Comment: I'm very grateful for that too @mklement0

Answer (score -1):

The default field separator in awk is the space.  So you are only printing the first word in the string passed to awk.

You can specify the field separator on the command line with -F[field separator]

Example, setting the field separator to a comma:

```
$ echo "Hello World" | awk -F, '{print $1}'      
Hello World
```

Comment: Yes, but when you change the field separator he will bring the entire line **VAR3 'Hello World'**

Comment: @AbdelP. The `,` is just an example (aside from the fact that it should be `-F,`, not `-FS,`; the _option_ `-F` translates into the _variable_ `FS` inside the `awk` script), but a _single-character_ value cannot solve your problem.